# Shouldn't [the-little-mermaid] include the original as well instead of just the Disney adaptation?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the usage guidance for [the-little-mermaid](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-little-mermaid) does not even acknowledge the existence of the original story, reading:

> For questions regarding Walt Disney's The Little Mermaid. Always use in conjunction with the [disney] tag.

However, the original story by Hans Christian Andersen is on topic as well. We currently have two questions about it that are *not* about the Disney adaptation:

- [Marionette version of "The Little Mermaid"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270898/19561)
- [ID an adaptation of The Little Mermaid with dark scary atmosphere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/270876/19561)

Should we edit the usage guidance to include the original?

Comment: I didn't even know Walt Disney had anything to do with this classic Andersen fairy tale. Obviously the tag should be about the actual story, not only whatever screen adaptations have been made over the years.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

The tag should include the original and all adaptations. The usage guidance should reflect this, possibly mentioning the Disney adaptation since this is the one that's most well known. Neither of the Disney adaptations has enough questions to warrant their own tag.

The usage guidance could read:

> For questions regarding Hans Christian Andersen's fairy tale, including adaptations. Use in conjunction with [disney] when asking about any of the Disney versions.